# infinite set and set of part

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that if $E$ is an infinite, therefore the set of part $\mathcal P(E)$ is infinite. I know that if $E$ is infinite, so $$\forall x\in E, \{x\}\in \mathcal  P(E)$$ and so $\mathcal  P(E)$ is infinite. But can I do like this:

If $E$ is infinite, then, there is a subset $A\subset E$ which is countable. Let denote $A=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ where $x_i\in E$ for all $i$. Consider a subset $B_n\subset A$ which is finite and contain $n$ element of $A$. We know that $\mathcal  P(B_n)=2^n$. Moreover, $$\lim_{n\to\infty } B_n=A$$
and $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\mathcal P(B_n)=\mathcal  P(A)\subset \mathcal  P(E).$$

Therefore 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }|\mathcal P(A)|=\lim |\mathcal  P(B_n)|=\lim_{n\to\infty }2^n=\infty .$$

Then, we can conclude that $\mathcal  P(A)$ is infinite, and so that $\mathcal  P(E)$ is infinite too.

Is it correct ?

Comment: The argument is needlessly complicated, and incorrect in several ways. For intance, you have not defined the meaning of the symbols you are using. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n=A$ simply means that $\bigcup_n B_n=A$, then why don't you just say so, instead of bringing in the language of symbols? Anyway, if that's the meaning, then this does not follow from what you said (that each $B_n$ is a subset of $A$ of size $n$). For instance, $A$ could be $\mathbb N$, and $B_n$ could consist of $n$ primes. We could even have the $B_n$ to be pairwise disjoint, and then talking of limits makes even less sense.

Comment: Your idea is correct, but the formalization is not. You are using in an improper way the symbol $\lim_{n \to +\infty}$

Comment: Even if you fix this, so $B_0\subset B_1\subset B_2\subset\dots$, and $\bigcup_n B_n=A$, it is still false that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathcal P(B_n)=\mathcal P(A)$. Again, you have not defined the symbols being used, but if the limit notation is to mean the same as in the previous time you used it (union), then $\bigcup_n\mathcal P(B_n)$ is most definitely not $\mathcal P(A)$. Instead, it is the  collection of *finite* subsets of $A$, which is far from the full power-set. Now, one of course can say that this is even better, since all you want is to check that $\mathcal P(E)$ is infinite.

Comment: **Andres Caicedo:** Thanks for the counter example, I would never think about that. Could you correct my proof to give it correct ? I would really appreciate :-)

Comment: But if that's the case, then the argument using just singletons is better still. It is a bit jarring to go your route. Then there is the punchline, where you use limits in the sense of calculus. But this is menaingless now since you are arguing about cardinalities, and the sizes of infinite sets are not the infinities that appear in calculus. Even if one ignores all of this, there is an issue of a different nature, namely that your proof is "wasteful" since it needs to assume some amount of the axiom of choice, while the theorem itself does not require this.

Comment: What Crustul says is correct, with the caveat that in absence of choice, this works only for one definition of "infinite" (the one due to Dedekind). The singletons argument is simpler, more elegant and more general.

Comment: Indeed, without choice, an infinite set does not need to contain a countably infinite subset. The text/course you are foillowing is probably assuming choice, so this is not a serious issue, except that we should strive to avoid this wastefulness in our arguments. The result is more elegance, and a better understanding of why the results we are arguing for are actually true, which is really what matters.

Comment: So taking $B_n=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ would be enough to conclude ?

Answer (score 0):

You used the symbol $\lim_{n \to +\infty}$ in an improper and intuitive way, but not correctly. The problem is that cardinal numbers are not usual numbers, and the fact that they are ordered is a very subtle thing.

You should have argued as follows:

I want to show that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(E)$ is bigger than $n$.

Let $\{ x_i\} \subseteq E$ an infinite countable subset. Then
$$n < 2^n = |\mathcal{P}(\{ x_1, \dots, x_n\})| \leq |\mathcal{P}(E)|$$
where the last inequality follows since $\mathcal{P}(\{ x_1, \dots, x_n\} \subseteq\mathcal{P}(E) $.